# Looping XML containing a few child and children to output as a table in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach, xmldom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Agenda>
        <responseMessage>Success.</responseMessage>
        <jobs>
            <trip>
                <header>
                    <reservation_number>10562</reservation_number>
                    <recipient_first>John</recipient_first>
                    <recipient_middle>H</recipient_middle>
                    <recipient_last>Doe</recipient_last>
                </header>
                <legs>
                    <leg>
                        <trip_id>42390</trip_id>
                        <leg_status>Active</leg_status>
                        <pickup_date>12/24/2020</pickup_date>
                        <pickup_time>0600</pickup_time>
                        <pickup_state>New York</pickup_state>
                        <pickup_country>USA</pickup_country>
                        <dropoff_state>Pennsylvania</dropoff_state>
                        <dropoff_country>USA</dropoff_country>
                    </leg>
                    <leg>
                        <trip_id>42391</trip_id>
                        <leg_status>Canceled</leg_status>
                        <pickup_date>01/02/2021</pickup_date>
                        <pickup_time>1800</pickup_time>
                        <pickup_state>Pennsylvania</pickup_state>
                        <pickup_country>USA</pickup_country>
                        <dropoff_state>New York</dropoff_state>
                        <dropoff_country>USA</dropoff_country>
                    </leg>
                </legs>
                <secondary_services>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>42390</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>Tolls</service_name>
                        <service_rate>3.00</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>1</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>42390</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>addtl.miles</service_name>
                        <service_rate>3.40</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>25</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>42391</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>Tolls</service_name>
                        <service_rate>18.00</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>1</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>42391</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>addtl.miles</service_name>
                        <service_rate>3.40</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>29</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                </secondary_services>
            </trip>
            <trip>
                <header>
                    <reservation_number>10575</reservation_number>
                    <recipient_first>Emily</recipient_first>
                    <recipient_middle></recipient_middle>
                    <recipient_last>Santana</recipient_last>
                </header>
                <legs>
                    <leg>
                        <trip_id>64593</trip_id>
                        <leg_status>Active</leg_status>
                        <pickup_date>12/27/2020</pickup_date>
                        <pickup_time>1700</pickup_time>
                        <pickup_state>New York</pickup_state>
                        <pickup_country>USA</pickup_country>
                        <dropoff_state>Connecticut</dropoff_state>
                        <dropoff_country>USA</dropoff_country>
                    </leg>
                    <leg>
                        <trip_id>64594</trip_id>
                        <leg_status>Active</leg_status>
                        <pickup_date>01/04/2021</pickup_date>
                        <pickup_time>1200</pickup_time>
                        <pickup_state>Connecticut</pickup_state>
                        <pickup_country>USA</pickup_country>
                        <dropoff_state>New York</dropoff_state>
                        <dropoff_country>USA</dropoff_country>
                    </leg>
                </legs>
                <secondary_services>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>64593</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>Tolls</service_name>
                        <service_rate>0.00</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>0</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>64593</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>addtl.miles</service_name>
                        <service_rate>3.40</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>10</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>64594</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>Tolls</service_name>
                        <service_rate>04.00</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>1</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <service_leg_id>64594</service_leg_id>
                        <service_name>addtl.miles</service_name>
                        <service_rate>3.40</service_rate>
                        <service_quantity>11</service_quantity>
                    </service>
                </secondary_services>
            </trip>
        </jobs>
    </Agenda>
```

I am having trouble looping through an foreach loop to output a table such as this one.

| Reservation ID | Status | Name | Date | Time | PU Location | DO Location | Tolls | Addlt. Miles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10562-42390 | Active | John H Doe | 12/24/2020 | 0600 | New York, USA | Pennsylvania, USA | 3.00 | 25 |
| 10562-42391 | Canceled | John H Doe | 01/02/2021 | 1800 | Pennsylvania, USA | New York, USA | 18.00 | 29 |
| 10575-64593 | Active | Emily Santana | 12/27/2020 | 1700 | New York, USA | Connecticut, USA | 0.00 | 10 |
| 10575-64594 | Active | Emily Santana | 01/04/2021 | 1200 | Connecticut, USA | New York, USA | 4.00 | 11 |

I've tried a foreach loop with keys and values inside another foreach loop but I was unable to match the service element with the leg element as they have their independent loops.

Comment: Can you show the code that does the matching as it may be easier to fix than come up with a completely new solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files such as handling all the concatenation of values and matching of leg ids. If needed, XSLT can even convert to HTML. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its [xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class using `DOMDocument` library.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="leg_key" match="leg" use="trip_id" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/Agenda">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::leg[generate-id() =
                                                         generate-id(key('leg_key', trip_id)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="leg">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="curr_leg_id" select="trip_id"/>
            <Reservation_id>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::trip/header/reservation_number, '-', trip_id)"/>
            </Reservation_id>
            <Status><xsl:value-of select="leg_status"/></Status>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::trip/header/recipient_first, ' ', 
                                               ancestor::trip/header/recipient_middle, ' ', 
                                               ancestor::trip/header/recipient_last)"/></Name>
            <Date><xsl:value-of select="pickup_date"/></Date>
            <Time><xsl:value-of select="pickup_time"/></Time>
            <PU_location><xsl:value-of select="concat(pickup_state, ' ', pickup_country)"/></PU_location>
            <DO_location><xsl:value-of select="concat(dropoff_state, ' ', dropoff_country)"/></DO_location>
            <Tolls>
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::trip/secondary_services/service[service_leg_id = $curr_leg_id and
                                                                                service_name='Tolls']/service_rate"/>
            </Tolls>
            <Addl>
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::trip/secondary_services/service[service_leg_id = $curr_leg_id and
                                                                                service_name='addtl.miles']/service_quantity"/>
            </Addl>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkr/2)</kbd>

**PHP** *(use `$new_xml` for final end-use needs)*

```php
// LOAD XML
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('/path/to/Input.xml');

// LOAD XSLT 
$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xsl->load('/path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl');

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// TRANSFORM ORIGINAL DOCUMENT
$new_xml = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);

// ECHO TO SCREEN 
echo $new_xml->saveXML();

// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents('/path/to/Output.xml', $new_xml);
```

Comment: You are definitely the GOAT ! Applying the power of XSLT to transform XML data gives unlimited amount of capabilities (Matching especially). Thank You!

Comment: Yes!! Finally, someone sees the power of XSLT (outside of `xslt` thread)! Happy coding!

Comment: Perhaps more than just a New Years resolution: recognizing the power of XSLT - therefore Happy New Year :+)

Comment: @Parfait Thank You! you just open someones eyes into XSLT 